# C code equivalent to serial monitor commands like Serial.begin,serial.flush,serial.read,serial.available,etc

Tags: serial-port, arduino-ide

Hi I am trying to learn coding microcontrollers on my own. I am trying to code my arduino board (ATMEGA8A-PU) in embedded C using the arduino ide itself. I have blinked my LED so far. Now I am trying to control its state using the serial monitor(sending "on" lights it up and "off" switches it off). But I don't know the C commands to do it.I successfully did it using the arduino Serial commands.

```
int led = 13; // Pin 13

void setup()
{
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // Set pin 13 as digital out

   // Start up serial connection
   Serial.begin(9600); // baud rate
    Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
  String input = "";

// Read any serial input
while (Serial.available() > 0)
{
    input += (char) Serial.read(); // Read in one char at a time
    delay(5); // Delay for 5 ms so the next char has time to be received
}

if (input == "on")
{
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // on
}
else if (input == "off")
{
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); // off
}
}
```

So please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Serial class and functions like begin(), print() etc from the Serial class which is C++ language. These are the C++ commands native to the Arduino development environment. So anyway you ar using C/C++ commands here.